# How to access the another view inside listener?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom list view in which i some buttons.OnClick of buttons i am trying to change their colors but some how i am not able to do it.

```
holder.clean.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                        //  Log.i("SYNC", "camera"+String.valueOf(index));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C6614"));
                        v.getParent().findViewById(R.id.dirty_view_id).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                        v.getParent().findViewById(R.id.na_view_id).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                        v.getParent().findViewById(R.id.dc_view_id).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                        Status = "1";

                        index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                        Log.i("SYNC", String.valueOf(index));

                        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(new Date());

                        db.updateInspectionDetails(inspection_id, user_id,
                                location_inspection_array.get(position)
                                        .getComponentid(), subclient_id, client_id,
                                Status, images_path_string, timeStamp);

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

**EDIT**
**Get View Method**

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            select_postion=position;
            Log.i("error","select--"+select_postion);
            note_pos = position;
             View rowView = convertView;
             if (convertView == null) 
             {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                    rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null, true);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    holder.componentName = (TextView) rowView
                            .findViewById(R.id.location_list_row);
                    holder.clean = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                    holder.dirty = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
                    holder.dc = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
                    holder.na = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn4);
                    holder.camra = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
                    holder.camra.setTag(position);
                    holder.notes = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn6);
                    holder.count_text = (TextView) rowView
                            .findViewById(R.id.circle_count);
                    holder.red_circle = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_red);
                    // String img = location_obj.getImages();
                    // Log.i("IMG", img);
                    holder.clean.setTag(position);
                    holder.camra.setTag(position);
                    holder.na.setTag(position);
                    holder.dc.setTag(position);
                    holder.notes.setTag(position);
                    holder.dirty.setTag(position);


                    rowView.setTag(holder);

             }
             else 
             {
                    holder=(ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
             }

                    LocationInspectionBean location_obj = values.get(position);
                    if (location_inspection_array.get(position).getImages() != null) {

                        imgpath = location_inspection_array.get(position).getImages();

                        imgpath1 = imgpath.split(",");
                        count = imgpath1.length;
                        holder.red_circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.count_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.count_text.setText(String.valueOf(count));

                    }

                    final String a = String.valueOf(position);

                    holder.componentName.setText(location_obj.getComp_name());

                    if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C6614"));
                    }
                    if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                        holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FC4E3B"));
                    }
                    if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
                        holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0D6CC3"));
                    }
                    if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                        holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E87403"));
                    }
                    if (location_obj.getNotes().isEmpty()) {
                        holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));

                    }
                    if (location_obj.getNotes().isEmpty()) {
                        holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));

                    }


                    holder.clean.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                            //  Log.i("SYNC", "camera"+String.valueOf(index));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C6614"));
                            holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            Status = "1";

                            index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                            Log.i("SYNC", String.valueOf(index));

                            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(new Date());

                            db.updateInspectionDetails(inspection_id, user_id,
                                    location_inspection_array.get(position)
                                            .getComponentid(), subclient_id, client_id,
                                    Status, images_path_string, timeStamp);

                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    holder.dirty.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                            //  Log.i("SYNC", "camera"+String.valueOf(index));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FC4E3B"));
                            holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            Status = "3";

                            component_id_note = location_inspection_array.get(position)
                                    .getComponentid();

                            // db.updateInspectionDetails(inspection_id, user_id,
                            // location_inspection_array.get(position)
                            // .getComponentid(), subclient_id, client_id,
                            // Status, images_path_string, images_time_string);

                            intent = new Intent(getContext(), Notes.class);

                            intent.putExtra("client_id", client_id);
                            intent.putExtra("component_id_note", a);
                            intent.putExtra("inspection_id", inspection_id);
                            intent.putExtra("subClient_id", subclient_id);
                            intent.putExtra("sub_client_name", sub_client_name);
                            context.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                            context.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,
                                    R.anim.slide_out);

                        }
                    });



                    holder.na.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                            //  Log.i("SYNC", "camera"+String.valueOf(index));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0D6CC3"));
                            holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            Status = "4";

                            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(new Date());

                            db.updateInspectionDetails(inspection_id, user_id,
                                    location_inspection_array.get(position)
                                            .getComponentid(), subclient_id, client_id,
                                    Status, images_path_string, timeStamp);

                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    holder.dc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                            //  Log.i("SYNC", "camera"+String.valueOf(index));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E87403"));
                            holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                            Status = "2";
                            component_id_note = location_inspection_array.get(position)
                                    .getComponentid();

                            intent = new Intent(getContext(), Notes.class);
                            intent.putExtra("client_id", client_id);
                            intent.putExtra("inspection_id", inspection_id);
                            intent.putExtra("component_id_note", a);
                            intent.putExtra("subClient_id", subclient_id);
                            intent.putExtra("sub_client_name", sub_client_name);
                            context.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                            context.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,
                                    R.anim.slide_out);

                        }
                    });



                    holder.camra.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                        //  Log.i("SYNC", "camera"+String.valueOf(index));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            Camera(location_inspection_array.get(index).getClientid(),
                                    location_inspection_array.get(index)
                                            .getSubclientid(),
                                    location_inspection_array.get(index)
                                            .getComponentid(),
                                    location_inspection_array.get(index).getComp_name());

                        }

                    });

                    holder.notes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            component_id_note = location_inspection_array.get(position)
                                    .getComponentid();

                            intent = new Intent(getContext(), Notes.class);

                            intent.putExtra("client_id", client_id);
                            intent.putExtra("component_id_note", a);
                            intent.putExtra("inspection_id", inspection_id);
                            intent.putExtra("subClient_id", subclient_id);
                            intent.putExtra("sub_client_name", sub_client_name);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            context.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,
                                    R.anim.slide_out);

                        }
                    });
```

I am just able to change the color of the current button which is being clicked.If i try to access the view the it given me error

findViewById Is not defined for ViewParent.So please tell me how can i solve the problem.

Comment: check if v.getParent() is instance of `View` class and the cast it to `View`

Comment: why you don't use `holder` in `onTouch` as holder has all view object?

Comment: with holder i am not able to change the color of the other button.@shayanpourvatan

Comment: can you post code for that i can try on that @Selvin

Comment: why you can't? if you use viewHolderPattern (viewHolder object that contain all view object ) you can get all other view, please post holder class.

Comment: code? do you know java's basics ? instanceof operator? and casting?

Comment: but ... @shayanpourvatan solution looks better for me

Comment: check my updated code.@shayanpourvatan

Comment: what you want to do? for example you want change anything on `notes`, you can use : `holder.notes.setBackgroundColor......` or any other method that you want

Comment: y u are not declaring them globally ... initialize them in oncreate and use in On touch+

Comment: I want to change color of current button which is clicked & set a one color on other butttons.

Comment: what to declare globally?@koutuk

Comment: create one method like `setDefaultColor()` and change all background color to default ( "one color on other buttons" ) then use `view` argument for changing color of selected `view` to anything you want

Comment: store position inside holder ... then instead storing position in view's tags store holder there ... now you be able to get the holder corelated with view inside onTouch callback `holder.clean.setTag(position);` => `holder.postion = position; holder.clean.setTag(holder);`  in onTouch: `index = (Integer)v.getTag();` => `ViewHolder h = (ViewHolder)v.getTag(); index = h.position;` and now instead `xxx.findViewById(R.id.dirty_view_id)` use `holder.dirty`

Comment: I am doing like this also.holder.na.setbackground.... but this is not working so i tried to use v.getParent.PLease see my code.@shayanpourvatan

Comment: is not better to have one value to check view colors and instead of this dirty code and many listener use one simple switch case to set color, and changing that value in `onClick` and `onToach` ? i can't get anything from your code, but if `v.getParent` solve your problem so it's very good.

Comment: another issue is i am able to get the change color using your approach only for first & last item but not for other items

Comment: can you post your code as an answer@Selvin